# How to find touched Node within a UIRotationRecognizer (SpriteKit + Swift 3.0)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3

I have three nodes `lineBlock` of the same class `MovableBlock` on the screen. I want to rotate the `lineBlock` node someone is touching on the screen.

I've solved this for moving the correct `lineBlock` node in touchedMoved:

```
   override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        touch = touches.first!
        positionInScene = self.touch?.location(in: self)
        let previousPosition = self.touch?.previousLocation(in: self)
        let translation = CGVector(dx: (positionInScene?.x)! - (previousPosition?.x)!, dy: (positionInScene?.y)! - (previousPosition?.y)!)

        if touchedNode?.name?.contains("LineBlock") == true {
                (touchedNode as! MovableBlock).selected = true
                (touchedNode as! MovableBlock).parent!.parent!.run(SKAction.move(by: translation, duration: 0.0))
        }
    }
```

But I have not been able to do the same within my UIRotationRecognizer function. In my rotate function, it simply rotates the first node, regardless of which lineBlock (of class MovableBlock) I am touching:

```
func rotate(_ sender: UIRotationGestureRecognizer){
        if lineBlock.selected == true {
                lineBlock.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: (-(self.rotationRecognizer?.rotation)!*2), duration: 0.0))
                rotationRecognizer?.rotation = 0
        }
    }
```

For reference, here's how I define touchedNode (in touchBegan):

```
    touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    touch = touches.first!
    positionInScene = self.touch?.location(in: self)
    touchedNode = self.atPoint(positionInScene!)
```

Comment: would love to use touchedNode but touchedNode becomes nil outside of touchBegan or touchMoved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIGestureRecognizer`s have a `location(in:UIView)` method. You can use `self.view?.convert(sender.location(in: self.view), to: self)` to get the `UIRotationGestureRecognizer`'s location and use logic similar to that in `touchesBegan`.

`convert(_:to:)` will make sure that the point is in your scene's coordinate space.